# using object store with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ceph

I am pretty new to programming still and am now trying to store files, I was thinking of using an object store as my app is going to store pictures and videos however I am having a hard time finding documentation on some good ways to implement this. I am using express also if that changes anything.

There is documentation on Ceph and SUSE (2 that I am learning about) however I cannot find anything on Node and working with these storage systems. Can anyone point me in a good direction or resources please?

Comment: why not just simply use ceph package from npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/swift-ceph and here is quick-start: http://docs.ceph.com/docs/jewel/start/quick-ceph-deploy/  more deeply You'll learn experimenting

Comment: I saw that but that only has 66 downloads in the last month, Im not sure if its battle tested or not. there is another one `ev-store` with a lot more use however there isnt a lot of documentation on it and was confusing.

Do you use swift-ceph?

Comment: Actually there are not so many ceph users to see big download numbers for this package. In real You've to go by quick start and so on in docs You'll find it. I'm not using ceph, cuz there are Azure, Amazon Cloud services that all of world uses. It's enough.